# IntelliJ - How to get code visible as it is without suggestions/additions from IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]How to get rid of this highlighted part. It is not code but IntelliJ is trying to make this code more readable by suggesting this. It is super irritating

I expect code to be viewed in simple way

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the inlay hints for everything from IntelliJ settings and Now issue is resolved